# Android Admob : “Failed to load ad : 0”

Tags: android, admob

I have a problem with the new admob

```
    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    AdListener listener = new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            super.onAdClosed();

            Log.i("AdListener", "onAdClosed");
        }
        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            super.onAdFailedToLoad(errorCode);

            Log.i("AdListener", "onAdFailedToLoad---->"+errorCode);
        }
        @Override
        public void onAdLeftApplication() {
            super.onAdLeftApplication();

            Log.i("AdListener", "onAdLeftApplication");
        }
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded();

            Log.i("AdListener", "onAdLoaded");
        }
        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {
            super.onAdOpened();

            Log.i("AdListener", "onAdOpened");
        }
    };
    mAdView.setAdListener(listener);
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

app->build.gradle

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Here is what I get :

W/Ads﹕ There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0 W/Ads﹕

Failed to load ad: 0